# clarifying wolfram alpha log representation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I typed loglogn into WolframAlpha and saw under the "Alternative representations" it shows the result ${\log}({\log}(n)) = {\log(a)}{\log_a({\log}(n))}$. I'm confused because it appears there's a $\log$ base $a$. Then what base is the ${\log(a)}$ and ${\log}(n)$ and what rule was applied to represent that equation?

Comment: Not entirely sure what log rule was used, but on WolframAlpha $\log x$ is generally applied for logarithms with base $e$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally on WolframAlpha, $\log x$ is used to indicate a logarithm with base $e$, which is what I will use here. Applying the change of base formula,

$\log(\log (n))=\displaystyle\frac{\log_a (\log(n))}{\log_a (e)}$.

Using the change of base formula on $\log_a (e)$,

$\log_a (e) =\displaystyle\frac{\log (e)}{\log (a)}=\displaystyle\frac{1}{\log (a)}$.

Therefore,

$\begin{align}\log(\log (n))&=\displaystyle\frac{\log_a (\log(n))}{\log_a (e)}\\
&=\displaystyle\frac{\log_a(\log(n))}{\frac{1}{\log (a)}}\\
&=\log (a) \log_a (\log(n)) \qquad \qquad \blacksquare
\end{align}$

Answer (score 1):

This is just the application of the logarithm rule $\log_b(c)=\frac{\log(c)}{\log(b)}$

$${\log(a)}\cdot {\log_a({\log}(n))}=\log(a)\cdot \frac{\log(\log(n))}{\log(a)},$$

where $\log(\cdot )$ is the logarithm of base $e$. The factor $\log(a)$ can be cancelled.

Comment: did you mean to write $\log(\cdot)$?

Comment: @randomvalue The dot $\cdot$ is a placeholder for the argument of the function. It can be $a, e, x, ....$. So it represents $\log(a),  \log(e)... $ The crucial point is that $\log(\cdot)$ represents the logarithm of base $e$, regardless of the argument.